# subset one predictor coefplot() r

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, coefplot

I would like to display the confidence interval for a single predictor with coefplot() or to change the scale of the x-axis to logarithmic.

I run

```
fit_tripadvisor <- lm(price ~ bedrooms + bathrooms + accommodates + shared + private + tripAdvisorScore , data=manhattan_listings)
coefplot_Airbnb_TripAdvisor <- coefplot(fit_tripadvisor, predictors="tripAdvisorScore")
```

the first line works on building my linear model, but the second lines is giving me the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Term", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 42
```

The methodology described by @Lyzander in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807860/subset-of-predictors-using-coefplot) did not seem to work. Any suggestions?